# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre main con y sin parámetros?

Tags: c++

En muchos cursos de C++ he visto personas que escriben la función principal pasando parámetros y otros que no, de la siguientes formas:

Sin parámetros:

```
void main (){ }

int main (){ }
```

Con parámetros:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿A que se debe esto y que función desempeñan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo de la necesidad del programa es su utilización o no del paso de parámetros a la función principal. Por ejemplo hay varios programas que se utilizan en la consola y es mas fácil introducir el parámetro por ahí que ingresando al archivo y editarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de parámetros depende de la necesidad de datos que tenga la función, es recomendado según el libro código limpio, usar pocos o ningún argumento esto para reducir los tiempos de respuesta (microsegundos pero en procesos grandes seria valioso). En conclusión se emplean o no los parámetros según la necesidad.